# application crash with didRecieveData for UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ipad

```
 -[__NSCFType appendData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa054a60
    2012-08-13 15:58:31.892 SDTest1[3441:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType appendData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa054a60'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x1c18022 0x33e3cd6 0x1c19cbd 0x1b7eed0 0x1b7ecb2 0x937b 0x2a96a80 0x2a94e84 0x2a95ea7 0x2a94e3f 0x2a94fc5 0x29d99da 0x389c585 0x389b54a 0x389b861 0x37c5120 0x389b117 0x37c4fbf 0x1bec94f 0x1b4fb43 0x1b4f424 0x1b4ed84 0x1b4ec9b 0x3ac47d8 0x3ac488a 0x2093626 0x2b7d 0x2af5)
    terminate called throwing an exception

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{

    [webData appendData:data];

}
```

It saying ExcBadAccess....

This error i got while integrating my project class into another project.  I include all file and interface builder too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is saying that the object receiving the `appendData:` message is not what you think it is.  It looks as if your `webData` object has been deallocated and the memory reused for something else (`__NSCFType`).

If it's not obvious to you how the object is being released, you can run your program with Instruments and check for Zombies it may help with debugging.

Comment: zombies.  it means object never been dealloced.  May i know where i can enable for the object to  set zombie

Comment: If you choose the Product->Profile menu option, it should show you a choice of "instruments" to use with your app.  Select the "Zombie" one and, when it gets an error, you can examine the object's history.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
-[__NSCFType appendData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

says that you're sending a message to the wrong type.  I guess you're expecting an NSMutableData instance?

I don't recognize NSCFType, but this blog says it may be a symptom of memory management issues.  Maybe an early release.

http://imlocation.wordpress.com/2007/09/13/strange-objects-nscftype-indicate-memory-management-bugs/